# Google Map Api v2 Outof memory error Android

Tags: android, google-maps, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using google map api v2 for android.
Here is my code of fragment class
**mapview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:mySwitch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlmain"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/rlheader"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/header" >
</include>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rlheader"       
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    /> 

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**MapViewFragment**

```
       import java.io.File;
       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.Arrays;
       import java.util.HashMap;
       import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
       import org.json.JSONArray;
       import org.json.JSONObject;
       import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
       import android.content.Context;
       import android.location.Location;
       import android.location.LocationManager;
       import android.os.Build;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.os.Handler;
       import android.os.Looper;
       import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
       import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.view.LayoutInflater;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;
       import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
       import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.ImageButton;
       import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
       import android.widget.TextView;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
       import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapViewFragment extends BaseFragment{

 private RelativeLayout ll;
 ImageButton ivbtShopList,ivbtSearch;
 TextView tvHeader;
 private LocationManager locationManager;
 private String provider;
 Location location;
 ThreadPreLoader mTask;
 Handler mHandler;
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 ArrayList<DataOfPlaceList> Placelist=new ArrayList<DataOfPlaceList>();
 HashMap<String,DataOfPlaceList> Placelistdata=new HashMap<String,DataOfPlaceList>();
 DataOfPlaceList data;
 JSONArray jsonArray;
 JSONObject jsonObject;
 String APILink,Jsonstring;
 String TAG="NearByShop";
 Button btBack;
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 Boolean Successfull=false,isDestory=false;
 TextView tv5kmRecord,tv10kmRecord,tvAllRecord;
 int maptype;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PlaceListProgressHolder.initHolder(getActivity(), "Loading...");
    Jsonstring=(String) getArguments().get("jsonresponse");
    maptype=mPrefs.getInt("maptype", 0);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(readyToGo()){
    if (ll == null) {
        ll = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
        tvHeader=(TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderTitle);
        tvHeader.setTypeface(tf);
        btBack=(Button)ll.findViewById(R.id.btBack);
        btBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btBack.setOnClickListener(OnBackClickListener);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        if(((TABActivity)mActivity).checkConnection()){
            mTask = new ThreadPreLoader(PlaceListProgressHolder);
            mTask.execute();
            mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
          Log.e("remove","noremove");
     } else {
         ((ViewGroup) ll.getParent()).removeView(ll);
         Log.e("remove","yesremove");
     }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    return ll;
}
private OnClickListener OnBackClickListener=new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        isDestory=true;
        ((TABActivity)mActivity).onBackPressed();
    }

};
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ll == null) {
    tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.search));
    btBack.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.back));
    }
}
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        switch(maptype){
        case 0:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            break;
        case 1:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            break;
        case 2:
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            break;
        }

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mapinfowindow, null);


                return v;

            }
        });
        if(location!=null){
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        }

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(8));
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PlaceDetailsFragment fragment=new PlaceDetailsFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("placeid",""+Placelistdata.get(marker.getId()).getPlaceid());
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ((TABActivity)mActivity).pushFragments(AppConfig.TAB_B,fragment,true,true);
            }

        });


    }
  }

   private ProgressHolder PlaceListProgressHolder = new ProgressHolder() {

@Override
public boolean getMessagelist() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            Placelist.clear();
            jsonObject=new JSONObject(Jsonstring);
            Successfull=jsonObject.getBoolean("successfull");
            if(Successfull){
                jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("Place");
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    data=new DataOfPlaceList();
                    data.setPlaceid(jsonObject.getString("place_id"));
                    data.setPlacename(jsonObject.getString("placename"));
                    data.setFacility(jsonObject.optString("facility"));
                    data.setLatitude(jsonObject.getDouble("latitude"));
                    data.setLongitude(jsonObject.getDouble("longitude"));
                    data.setDistance(jsonObject.optDouble("distance"));
                    Placelist.add(data);
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void updateContent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(Successfull){
                    Log.i("Size",""+Placelist.size());
                    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                    for(int i=0;i<Placelist.size();i++){
                        setUpMap(Placelist.get(i));
                        builder.include(new LatLng(Placelist.get(i).getLatitude(),Placelist.get(i).getLongitude()));
                    }
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 10);
                    mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
            }


  }});
}

};



   private void setUpMap(DataOfPlaceList placelistdata) {
    Marker marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new  LatLng(placelistdata.getLatitude(),placelistdata.getLongitude())).title(""+placelistdata.getPlacename()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mapicon)).snippet(placelistdata.getFacility()));    
    Placelistdata.put(marker.getId(),placelistdata);
    /*LatLng latLng = new LatLng(shoplistdata.getLatitude(), shoplistdata.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLng, 0);
    LatLngBounds bounds=new LatLngBounds(latLng, latLng);
    mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);*/
  }

  class DataOfPlaceList{
    private String placeid;
    private String faciltiyid;
    private String placename;
    private Double distance;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public String getPlaceid(){
        return placeid;
    }
    public void setPlaceid(String placeid){
        this.placeid=placeid;
    }
    public String getFacility() {
        return faciltiyid;
    }

    public void setFacility(String faciltiyid) {
        this.faciltiyid = faciltiyid;
    }
    public String getPlacename() {
        return placename;
    }
    public void setPlacename(String placename) {
        this.placename = placename;
    }
    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public Double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public void setDistance(Double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

 }
   @Override
public void onDestroy() {
        super. onDestroyView(); 
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        if(fragment!=null && isDestory){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();

        trimCache(getActivity());
        }

}
@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isDestory=true;
    return false;

}

 }
```

**BaseFragment**

```
   import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
   import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

   public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
   public TABActivity mActivity;
   SharedPreferences mPrefs;
   Typeface tf;
   Boolean TABARefresh=false,TABBRefresh=false,TABCRefresh=false,TABDRefresh=false;
   protected static final String TAG_ERROR_DIALOG_FRAGMENT="errorDialog";
 /// For Email Validation////

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActivity       =   (TABActivity) this.getActivity();
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
    tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "PORKYS.TTF");
}

public boolean onBackPressed(){
    return false;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

}

 protected boolean readyToGo() {
        int status=
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());

        if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
          return(true);
        }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
          ErrorDialogFragment.newInstance(status)
                             .show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                                   TAG_ERROR_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
        }
        else {
             AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
                dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.no_maps)+" Please install latest google map and update google play service too.");
                dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        ((TABActivity)mActivity).onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
        }
        return(false);
      }

      public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        static final String ARG_STATUS="status";

        static ErrorDialogFragment newInstance(int status) {
          Bundle args=new Bundle();

          args.putInt(ARG_STATUS, status);

          ErrorDialogFragment result=new ErrorDialogFragment();

          result.setArguments(args);

          return(result);
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          Bundle args=getArguments();

          return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(args.getInt(ARG_STATUS),
                                                       getActivity(), 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dlg) {
          if (getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().finish();
          }
        }
      }

}
```

I am facing the same issue as posted here **http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766** and because of memory leaks outofmemory error comes while loading map.

Some time first time map will load shown but some time it will crash.
I have tested in Samsung TAB 2,Sony Erricson and also  SAMSUNG GALAXY X-Cover model GT-S5690 Android vers. 2.3.6 in Samsung XCover most of time it will crash and also in sony erricson it will crash some time.

I have also tested in emulator by in emulator if first time map will load and i come back second time than it will crash.

As **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases** the link this issue is resolved but not able to get how to solve it I have also tried using the generating new map key.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have pasted log here where many users are facing the same problem http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4766